# Having trouble deploying my Rails app on Heroku I get this - Error: Cannot find module '@babel/compat-data/corejs3-shipped-proposals'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, babeljs, babel-loader

I am working on a rails application. This application has been running fine, and I have successfully deployed it to Heroku many times. I recently made a lot of changes including adding Tailwindcss, as well as many database changes. The app works locally but when I deploy to Heroku I get:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
remote:        Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
remote:        Error: Cannot find module '@babel/compat-data/corejs3-shipped-proposals'
```

Any insight into why this will work locally but fail to deploy would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue in the CI pipeline for a Rails application.

Per https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/2383#issuecomment-683538859 I did the following to resolve my issue:

1. Added `"@babel/preset-env": "7.9.0"` to package.json (by the time you read this the version is likely out of date)
2. Ran `yarn install --check-files`
3. Ran `bin/rails webpacker:install`
4. Ran `bin/rails webpacker:compile`